# How to change the default number format in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have this column of string integers in the 'general' type all the time. Every time I open this spreadsheet, I have to convert it into 'number' type. But when I do it, it automatically creates two decimal points. For example, it changes '12345' to '12345.00'. It's kinds of annoying to use 'Decrease Decimal' every time. Is there any way to make two changes to the default mode?
1) Always assume that the column has 'number' type, not 'general' type
2) To not have any decimal points.

Comment: re: *'Every time I open this spreadsheet, ...'* - Are you saying that even if you change the number format (and save the workbook) the **same** workbook needs to have the number format adjusted the next time it is opened?

Comment: I paste big numbers into Excel all the time.  I want to see no decimal places and commas between the thousands.  Yes, I know how to set the format but I would like to have the format set when I open a new spreadsheet.  I'm guessing there is no option for that from what we see here.  What I would like to see is the ability to override the "general" number format that all numbers start out in when first entered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Excel Tips, Learn Excel \ Raghu R](https://quadexcel.com/how-to-set-up-excel-default-formatting/)

> Setting Formatting Options for Workbooks
>
> Excel does not offer many options that allow you to set formatting
>   defaults for your workbooks. However, you can work around this by
>   modifying the formatting in a blank workbook, then saving it as the
>   default template.
>
> 1. Open Excel to a blank workbook.
> 2. Format the blank file with all options desired. For example, set margins, cell color formats, or set up a header or footer. Make sure
>      to remove any values you entered in cells to test formatting unless
>      you want them to appear in every blank workbook.
> 3. Once your changes are made, click on the File tab and choose Save As.
> 4. From the “Files of type” drop-down list, select “Excel Template (*.xltx)” and change the file name to “Book.”
> 5. Set the “Save in” location to theXLSTART folder. This folder is typically located in a path similar to `C:Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office14/XLSTART`.
>
>    - The quickest way to find its location is to use the Immediate window in the Visual Basic Editor (VBE), as follows:
>    - Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to launch the VBE.
>    - If the Immediate window isn’t visible, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
>    - In the Immediate window, type `? application.StartupPath` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>    - VBA will display the path to XLStart.
> 6. Click Save.
> 7. Quit and re-open Excel. The blank workbook should contain the formatting you previously set.

Comment: Microsoft has a pretty similar support article here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-how-excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19

Comment: But what about setting the default number format only for when that format is selected? For example, it's useful to have the template start as General to allow for multiple formats. Then, if one has a set of columns that are going to be numbers, or currency, or accounting, it would be great to have a different format than Microsoft's default format. For example, never to display decimals, always to have a comma separator (or period in Europe). Is there a way to set *those* defaults outside of the direct formatting of the Book.xltx cells?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Right click on a column and click on `Format Cells...` and then select `Number` from `Category:` list and for `Decimal places:` specify 0

Save the file and re-open, and you should see that column be set to `Number`

**EDIT:**

If you want to apply formatting to **multiple excel files**, you can write a macro for that:

> Doing some quick research, came across the following VBA code --- I DO NOT take credit for this. I did however changed the `DoWork` method to add: `.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").NumberFormat = "Number"`

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Files\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xls")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
        DoWork wb
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    With wb
        'Do your work here
        .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").NumberFormat = "Number"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I mean there are actually multiple spreadsheets with the same format. So changing the format in one spreadsheet won't have any impact on the other spreadsheets. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @JunJang So if I understand correctly, you want a particular column (Say `Column G`, for example) to have the **same** format in all sheets within the excel workbook? If so, unless there are tens of 100s of sheets, I would still go with the proposed solution

Comment: No I meant there are multiple workbooks (I am sorry, I meant workbook before, not worksheet. Those two are a bit confusing).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put these styles into effect only if you select them (i.e., not as the default format for when you create a new file), then one way you can do it is to create new styles within that template (e.g., Book.xltx). For example, you can create a new style called "Currency (0)" that is equivalent to the style **$#,##0** for positive numbers. So, to use the desired format you would change the *style* of cell instead of using the *formatting controls*.

Yes, this is not ideal (it would be better to be able to change Excel's default functionality directly), but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the format as follows:

[image]

Once the file is saved the format will be retained.

Comment: I mean there are actually multiple spreadsheets with the same format. So changing the format in one spreadsheet won't have any impact on the other spreadsheets. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @JunJang  Then create some kind of template spreadsheet with proper formats, column widths, and re-use the template as a starting point.

Comment: I just followed this advice.  The text "Dec 24, 2023" was converted to the number "435418".  What does that number mean?  Why would that be considered a correct format given the text entered?

Answer (score 0):

wrote a tiny macro

```
    Sub PERS_FormatSelectionToNumberNoDecimals()
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    End Sub
```

... in my PERSONAL.XLSB.

In my data workbook's ***ThisWorkbook*** module (VBA editor) I place a function

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    ' Purpose   :   assign key shortcuts when workbook is activated
        Application.OnKey "^+o", "PERSONAL.XLSB!PERS_FormatSelectionToNumberNoDecimals"
    End Sub
```

... to assign the shortcut key CTRL-SHIFT-O (O as in other; you may assign another key of your choice) to the macro.

=> whenever you need to re-format a range to Number with 0 decimals, select the range and press the shortcut key.

In order to get rid of the key assignment when switching to another workbook you may place

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    ' Purpose   :   removes key short cut assignments if workbook is deactivated
        Application.OnKey "^+o"
    End Sub
```

...in my data workbook's ***ThisWorkbook*** module (VBA editor)

Answer (score 0):

I thought number format was stuck on a date and was reading this post to fix the problem when I realized the following.

Changing the number format in the Home Ribbon to, in my case, General that the next time I opened Excel (Office 365 Subscription version) the General format stayed! Problem solved.

[Home Ribbon, Number Format screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmn4L.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11 you can change the default number format across in Control Panel.

1. Open Control Panel
2. Choose "Clock and Region"
3. Choose "Region"
4. Choose "Additional Settings"
5. Choose the "Currency" tab
6. Change "No. of digits after decimal" from 2 to 0
7. Click Apply.