# Excel Number Format default to Time

Tags: excel, format, default

I have a bit of an annoying issues with an excel workbook around the default number format which I have been struggling to resolve.

In my spreadsheet the default number format looks to have been set to ‘Time’ (by default) so that even when I change the format and interest a new sheet the defaults is ‘Time’. This happen even after changing and restarting.

Is there a way to reset the Number formatting back for a workbook back to ‘General’?

ps I am using Excel 2013.

Thanks

Comment: Change the number format of the Normal cell style to General.

Comment: Doing that only works of the selected cell.

Comment: If changing the style doesn't work, then the other cells have been explicitly formatted.

Comment: What values are you entering in Excel? It will try to determine the most appropriate format. If you enter ##:## or #:## it will probably resolve to a time format. Just like entering 1/15 resolves to a date format. More info is needed to understand the issue. This is definitely not normal functionality. There isn't a way to set the default number format to anything other than General. As mentioned, excel will try to best fit the format based on the entry.

Comment: In the workbook that I have when I open a new sheet the default number format is setting itself to Time (Home -> Number -> Time) and not General. 

I'm trying to work out how to change that so that when I open a new sheet in the workbook that the default number format in not Time but just the default of General.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680465/how-to-change-the-default-number-format-in-excel?rq=1