# csv format hide decimal part when is opened with excel

Tags: excel, csv, text, notepad

I have a csv file. One column has a number with 2 decimal digits like 100,00. But hides the trailing zeros (100). When I open it with notepad is 100,00.

Comment: You can display them then by increasing the decimal.

Comment: ??? What is your question ???

Comment: At the time you **import** (not Open), the `CSV` file, you can tell Excel to designate that column as **Text**.  It will then retain the trailing zero's.  Exactly how to do this depends on your version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the mad world of CSVs and Excel.

That's one of the problems with the CSV files and excel: The value trailing zeros aren't shown by default. You can always modify the CSV within excel and then save it as `*.xls` or `*.xlsx` files.

There is no way to tell Excel to open a CSV with showing numbers per default with all given digits, if they are zero because excel does interpret them as "Standard".

If you don't need to work with the numbers as numbers you can always exchange the `,` with a `.` (that might be depending on the locale, not sure). Or just export it as a String:

The CSV:

```
test
="100,00"
13,37
100.00
=100,01
```

will produce the following output (locale de_DE):

[image]

In general, if you need to work with excel and want as much pre-formatted as possible, don't use CSV.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is just comma-separated values. Just values. No formatting hints are included. So you can't have a number's display format specified within the CSV -- the numbers will be displayed in whatever format Excel shows.

If you'd rather you can change the default display format in Excel (for all sheets, not just CSV's). Not what you're asking, but perhaps it will be your preference. See [How to change the default number format in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680465/how-to-change-the-default-number-format-in-excel) for details on that option.